# Can I run Powerline without Xorg

Tags: linux, bash, arch-linux

I installed powerline and its works fine  in Xfce terminal. 
I am using ArchLinux.
When I log in, pc always boot into cli mode. I like that. But in cli mode before satarting X, the bash prompt looks a little ugly than my previous .bashrc used to look. No colors for text and mixed with some colored blocks with prompt. 
Like    username■ ~ ■□.
It does not look the same it looks in Xfce terminal while I use tmux.

Most of time I work without DE or Xorg to learn about linux.

Is there any way to make powerline work in cli mode? Just like it works in gvim?
I searched but did not get any solution about this.

If thats not possible, is there any way to source a different .bashrc for my cli and different .bashrc for terminal emulator?

Comment: Please clarify how it looks ugly. Are you referring to the font?

Comment: It doesnt look good. Its mixing of text and some colored blocks. There are some colored blocks in between    user[block] ~ [block] _       I want text only prompt like

Comment: I want prompt like "user ~ $"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But in cli mode before satarting X, the bash prompt looks a little ugly than my previous .bashrc used to look. No colors for text and mixed with some colored blocks with prompt. Like username■ ~ ■□.

The Linux console is very limited in what fonts it supports – intentionally, AFAIK – so you likely won't be able to use it that way. (Though it's technically possible to make a powerlinified font there, but I couldn't find any.)

If you want advanced features, you'll need `kmscon` or `fbterm`.

> Most of time I work without DE or Xorg to learn about linux.

That doesn't make any sense at all. (It's like trying to learn film-making by watching movies on a black&white TV...) If anything, you'll only learn less.

> If thats not possible, is there any way to source a different .bashrc for my cli and different .bashrc for terminal emulator?

You can use $TERM to distinguish – the Linux console uses `linux` as the terminfo name.

```
if [ "$TERM" = "linux" ]; then
    PS1="(put simple prompt here)"
else
    PS1="(put fancy prompt here)"
fi
```

However, that won't help if you use tmux in console.

Comment: Fbterm is what i needed. Thanks. Kmscon did not work for some reason I dont know. Wow, such a simple bash script block could solve it. I dont know how to write bash scripts. I guess thats really helpful. And its just a personal preference to learn the hard way about linux. :)